# Orange (data mining) psycopg2 connect fail "Unsupported frontend protocol" with postgresql 12.2

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, orange, postgresql-12

https://orange.biolab.si/

Connect to postgresql 12.2 fails with:

Unsupported frontend protocol 123[wraps]

I believe this is:

https://github.com/petere/homebrew-postgresql/issues/51

I'm on Windows 18363.778 using Orange 3.25.0 and psycopg2-2.8.5.

Is there a fix/workaround for this? Kind of annoying. It's not easy finding a visualization tool that works with localhost postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomorrow's bug fix release (12.3) should contain a fix for this.  (Although I thought this was only a problem on Macs, so maybe you are seeing a related but different problem)

Comment: I don't think the platform should affect the behavior of these connects through psycopg2 so hopefully this will be a fix. Yay! Glad this may be done right away.

Been with PostgreSQL since before it knew SQL. ;)

Comment: Thank you -- works fine! At least the connect part!